# How do I use "while" and "end while" inside of the echo do_shortcode with ACF Repeater?

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I feel like I’m so close, but just need someone to help assist me with getting this working. I’m using a repeater field with Advanced Custom Fields and am using the echo shortcode, but only need part of it to repeat in the loop.

See my code below:

```
<?php
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('homepage_slider') ):
// loop through the rows of data

// display a sub field value
echo do_shortcode('
[ux_slider timer="4500" arrows="true" bullets="true" auto_slide="true" nav_color="light"]

' . while ( have_rows('homepage_slider') ) : the_row(); . '

[ux_banner bg=" ' . get_sub_field('slider_image') . ' " height="600px" text_color="light" text_align="center" text_pos="center" text_width="70%" parallax_text="0" parallax="3" effect="sparkle"]

<h1>' .  get_sub_field('slider_slide_title') . '</h1>
<h4 class="thin-font">' . get_sub_field('slider_sub_title') . '</h4>
[/ux_banner]

' . endwhile; . '

[/ux_slider]');

else :
// no rows found
endif;
?>
```

Seems to be the placement of the “while” and “endwhile”, but the ux_banner is the only shortcode I want to repeat. How do I use "while" and "end while" inside of the echo do_shortcode? Let me know if you have any thoughts/ideas, thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *generate* the shortcode within the loop, and then execute it afterwards:

```
if ( have_rows( 'homepage_slider' ) ) {
    $shortcode = '[ux_slider timer="4500" arrows="true" bullets="true" auto_slide="true" nav_color="light"]';

    while ( have_rows('homepage_slider') ) {
        the_row();

        $shortcode .=
'[ux_banner bg=" ' . get_sub_field( 'slider_image' ) . ' " height="600px" text_color="light" text_align="center" text_pos="center" text_width="70%" parallax_text="0" parallax="3" effect="sparkle"]
    <h1>' .  get_sub_field( 'slider_slide_title' ) . '</h1>
    <h4 class="thin-font">' . get_sub_field( 'slider_sub_title' ) . '</h4>
[/ux_banner]';

    }

    $shortcode .= '[/ux_slider]';

    echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Sooooo much!